# Java Akka FSM Illegal Forward Reference

Tags: java, akka, fsm, state-machine

I'm using Akka to implement FSM based on PartialFunction regarding the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/java/lambda-fsm.html). I'm having the following simplified FSM:

```
public class FMS extends AbstractActor {

    private PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> state1 = ReceiveBuilder
        .matchAny(o -> {
            //context().become(state2);
        })
        .build();

    private PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> state2 = ReceiveBuilder
        .matchAny(o -> {
            context().become(state1);
        })
        .build();
}
```

In this example it's legal to transition to `state1` from `state2`, but it is illegal to transition from `state1` from `state2`. The field `state2` is not declared yet for `state1`, so there is `Illegal Forward Reference` compilation error.

I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
public class FMS extends AbstractActor {

    private PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> state1;
    private PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> state2; 

    {
        state1 = getState1();
        state2 = getState2();
    }

    private PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> getState1() {
        return ReceiveBuilder
                .matchAny(o -> {
                    context().become(state2);
                })
                .build();
    }

    private PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> getState2() {
        return ReceiveBuilder
                .matchAny(o -> {
                    context().become(state1);
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

This code works, but I'm wondering is there any better and nice solution available here?

Akka version is 2.4.2.

Comment: You don't need those methods. Just initialize them inline in the initializer block.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it's possible, in this case the initialization block become huge, but it's looks better and shorter, thanks